# Differences between Js class naming

Tags: javascript, class, oop

```
class Ayhan{
  
}

let ayhan=class Ayhan{
  
} ;

let ayhan=class{
  
}
```

what is the different between this classes? Can I use anyone which I want?

Comment: Seems like an odd choice of duplicate considering that `class` doesn't hoist like `function`.

Comment: And:  the first example is the right one. The others will have developers looking at you funny.

Comment: note that the last example makes the class be named "ayhan", lower case "a".